# Is there a combinator for returning a Result based on a boolean condition?

Tags: error-handling, rust, boolean

For Option types, I frequently use the `ok_or` combinator to return errors like this:

```
let my_vec = [1,2,3];

let head = my_vec.first().cloned().ok_or(Error::MyError)?;
```

I am looking for a similar combinator or method to handle boolean values not Option types. For example:

```
let my_vec = [1,2,3];
let head = my_vec.is_empty().false_or(Error::MyError)?;
```

I often write matches to handle this, but it seems quite verbose:

```
let vec_is_ok = match my_vec.is_empty() {
    true => Err(...),
    false => Ok(())
}
vec_is_ok?;
```

Is there are more concise way to write this similar to the `ok_or` combinator that i can use on boolean values?

Comment: [boolinator](https://docs.rs/boolinator/2.4.0/boolinator/index.html) might be of help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a method `bool::then` (added in Rust 1.50.0), returning an `Option<T>` which you can convert into a `Result<T, E>`.

Your example would look like this:

```
use std::ops::Not;

my_vec.is_empty().not().then(|| ()).ok_or(MyError)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I often write matches to handle this, but it seems quite verbose:
>
> ```rust
> let vec_is_ok = match my_vec.is_empty() {
>     true => Err(...),
>     false => Ok(())
> }
> vec_is_ok?;
> ```

`if` is an expression and works with booleans:

```rust
let vec_is_ok = if my_vec.is_empty() { Err(...) } else { Ok(()) };
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Peter Hall's proposition is the older but richer [boolinator](https://crates.io/crates/boolinator) crate which provides [direct support for the `Result` type](https://docs.rs/boolinator/2.4.0/boolinator/trait.Boolinator.html#tymethod.as_result) e.g.

```rust
let vec_is_ok = my_vec.is_empty.not().as_result((), ...);
```

or

```rust
let vec_is_ok = my_vec.is_empty.not().ok_or(...)
```

the latter is basically the same as the former special-cased for the "success" case of `Ok(())` as that's common.

There's also `as_result_from` which takes two callbacks, if one (or both) payload requires expensive setup.